# How to call JavaScript after PrimeFaces DataTable row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I wanted to use the features from PrimeFaces DataTable so I've implemented the framework and rebuilt my current table (built with JSF) with the DataTable. Now I have a problem in that I don't know how I can call a JS function on row click.

This was my previous implementation:

```
onclick="onRowClick(this, event)"
```

With a JSF component it was possible to detect a row click. Now I want to implement this with PrimeFaces to detect the exactly the same row click in the DataTable.

Is there any simple way to deal with this? `onclick` is not available for this PrimeFaces component so I can't just copy this.

Comment: PrimeFaces IS a JSF component and clicking on a row  is build in in the datatable, it is called 'selection'. Check the PrimeFaces showcase. And where was your previous implementation applied?

Comment: You can add in datatable code like `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{yourBean.onSelect}" oncomplete="show()" />`. In this code `show` is remote command like `<p:remoteCommand name="show" action="someAction" />`.